# Go language: Using package name inside package scope (for Examples)

Tags: go

I am currently writing `ExampleFuncs` in my Go test scripts. For example:

```
package hello

import "testing"

func ExampleGetSymbol() {
    data := GetSymbol("AAPL")
    fmt.Println(len(data.Data))
    // Output: 21
}
```

Now, this gives me two benefits:

1. This example is executed when I am running `go test` and
2. It appears in the godoc documentation under `func GetSymbol`

One thing bothers me and I am wondering if there is anything I should do about it.
For the user that's trying to learn from this example, the line

```
data := GetSymbol("AAPL")
```

should actually be

```
data := hello.GetSymbol("AAPL")
```

but since the test is in the same scope as the package, I cannot use it like this.

So I guess the distilled version of my question would be:
Is there a way to allow `package.field` notation inside the package scope?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than putting this in package `hello`, put it in package `hello_test`. You're allowed to have both `hello` and `hello_test` packages in the same directory, and it allows (requires) you to create your examples the way you're suggesting.

Incidentally, this also causes you to write your test cases (at least for this file) only to the public API. This is often a good thing. But if you need to write to private functions, you can split your tests into separate files, some in the `hello` package and some in `hello_test`.

BTW, documentation for this is slightly buried. You can find it in the "Test packages" section of the [go cmd documentation](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages).

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know package_test is allowed. Did not see it mentioned in the testing document. This is perfect.